# After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 internet no longer connects

Tags: 16.04, networking, 18.04, upgrade

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04LTS to Ubuntu 18.04LTS the computer no longer connects to the internet (the upgrading itself was performed through the wired network, no fails at all).

After upgrading I turned the computer off and tried to use it a couple of days later. It pings OK (ping 8.8.8.8 runs at 43ms. to 45ms each response) and ifconfig does not show any weird message. I kept the same router and there are two other machines running U16.04 and they still connect OK.

I made no change at all in the machine, it was running perfectly well before upgrading. Can you just point me out to where to start investigating?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you mean by "no longer connects" but "It pings OK", since ping is a type of connection.  Do you mean you can't view web pages? If so, it is probably a firewall problem of some sort.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply.

Yep, that's it. Pings OK, but no page opens with valid URL (http or https). I use Firefox, the message for any attempt is always "We're having trouble finding that site". It used to work fine with Ubuntu 16.04, same hardware. Does Ubuntu 18.04 change firewall settings by its own? Any suggestion where to start investigating?

Comment: Edit your network connection in connection manager, or create new and dont forget to set DNS by dhcp or just 8.8.8.8 If I guess correctly you can ping, so network working, but problem can be in dns.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, I would suggest you reboot your modem and see what that effect has.  Leave it disconnected from power for a full half minute.
2. Secondly, you can ensure that you have networking enabled, and if that does nothing, try disabling your wired connection,(usually named "1") Then re-enable it.
3. You might also next try deleting the wired connection and then recreating a new one.
4. Did you enable your firewall?  GUFW.  Ensure you have outgoing connections allowed.

Comment: Hi, and thanks. I'll reboot the modem, but what  I do not understand is the fact that this computer (the one I'm using now) is connected to the same router/modem as the one that I upgraded to U18.04 (the upgrade was performed through the network). I have traded the ports with this computer and it still works, the upgraded one does not. I even let it alone with the router/modem. About the firewall, can you point me to any source of info that would guide me to check and set it up accordingly? Thanks.

Comment: (additional) When upgrading I was asked to update or to keep previous setting in, at least, three different moments. I all of them I decided to keep previous settings.